# Capturing mouse movements in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, onmousemove

I'm writing a game and need to capture mouse movements in Firefox. This is my code:

```
document.onmousemove = function(e) {
    mouseState.x = e.x;
    mouseState.y = e.y;
}
```

it works correctly in Chrome/IE however it doesn't seem to work in Firefox. When I do `console.log(mouseState.x)` it comes back as `undefined`.

What modifications do I need to make to get Firefox to capture mouse movements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `clientX` and `clientY` instead.

- [Firefox docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/MouseEvent)
- [w3specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-MouseEvent)

> Nobody can explain why we need x/y when we have clientX/Y. **Firefox’s** take on this property pair is by far the sanest(removed it-gdoron).

[quirks mode](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try using `e.clientX` and `e.clientY`.